# How to enable inbound connection for a particular port in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-iot-core-10, remote-connection

in windows 10 IoT i want to accept TCP packets on a port (eg:- 49856) from a remote machine.

Comment: This question is correct only,I dont know why people r putting negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try the following command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open mongod port 49856" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=49856
```